# YAML file found, but unable to parse content

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I'm trying to parse a YAML configuration file using yaml-cpp (https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp), Visual Studio 2019 Community.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    YAML::Node config;

    try
    {
        YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("conf.yml");
    }
    catch (YAML::BadFile e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.msg << std::endl;
        return (1);
    }
    catch (YAML::ParserException e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.msg << std::endl;
        return (1);
    }

    std::cout << config["window"] ? "Window found" : "Window not found" << std::endl;
    return (0);
}
```

Here's my YAML file :

```
---
window:
  width: 1280
  height: 720
...
```

But the result is always :

> Window not found

The loading is successful, but the content of the "config" node object seems empty. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *[variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)*:

```
YAML::Node config; // This is the config you print out at the end

try
{
    // The below config is local to the narrow try-scope, shadowing the
    // config you declared above.
    YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("conf.yml");
}
```

Correction:

```
YAML::Node config;

try
{
    config = YAML::LoadFile("conf.yml");
}
```

Also put parentheses around your ternary operator:

```
std::cout << (config["window"] ? "Window found" : "Window not found") << '\n';
```

Comment: I didn't know shadowing was a thing in C++, I thought it would have thrown an error, thus didn't think about it. Thank you for your help !